# Different behavior between generator expression and first constructing a list then using list-converted generator

Tags: python, generator

Can these two pieces of codes generate different behavior for downstream applications? In other words, are the returning objects any different ?

```
 return (func(i) for i in a_list)
```

and

```
 b_list=[] 
 for i in a_list:
     b_list.append(func(i))
 return (i for i in b_list)
```

PS: The second way to build generator is very questionable.

Comment: Yes, if the `func(i)` is influenced by the state of something external.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code:

```
b_list=[] 
for i in a_list:
    b_list.append(func(i))
return (i for i in b_list)
```

Is entirely the same as this code:

```
return iter([func(i) for i in a_list])
```

The difference between these and this:

```
return (func(i) for i in a_list)
```

Is that the latter is [*lazy*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) and the other two are *eager* - i.e the latter runs `func` every time its `__next__()` method is called and the other two run `func` for every item ia `a_list` immediately.

So, the answer depends whether `func` is a [pure function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function#Compiler_optimizations) - in this case, if it behaves the same regardless of when it is run and independently from external/global variables.

It also depends on whether the items of the list are mutable and if them or the list itself are changed by other code.

If the answers are respectively "yes" and "no", they are same save for their memory footprint.

Finally, as long we're discussing functional concepts, please consider using:

```
return map(func, a_list)
```

Instead of:

```
return (func(i) for i in a_list)
```

But only if you're using Python 3's lovely lazy `map()` and not Python 2's **evil** eager `map()`.